# How to integrate testcafe automation tool with laravel

Tags: laravel-5, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I have recorded the tests using testcafe tool. I want to integrate these tests into local code project laravel.

https://testcafe.devexpress.com/

But I am not using laravel browse testing because I have already recorded test in testcafe tool.

[image]

[image]

Please help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your scenario is unclear. Please let me know how you wish to integrate TestCafe tests into laravel. Do you want to record tests with TestCafe and run them in the "laravel" system?

Comment: @Marion yes i have record test in testcafe and integrate with laravel.
Because my project made in laravel.
if this is possible please explain this.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, you want to run your recorded TestCafe tests using lavarel.

If so, note that only TestCafe can run its own test cases.

If you are looking for TestCafe runner integration with laravel, it looks like such integration is not available:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/testing